# Shade a cell in excel based on split between variable and fixed cost - possible?

Tags: excel

I'm tying to visualize the results of a network transport model. Specifically, I would like to show the cost to deliver to a location from a given plant. Next, for that location, I would like to split the cell into two colors, based on the variable and fixed components of the total shipping cost. I don't think this is possible....but wanted to check if anyone might have done this. Screenshot shown:

[image: Sample Screenshot]

I'm hoping to change the size of green cell "Demand" by the amount of the total cost (in this case it would 25), and then split the cell itself into two colors, based on the ratios of the components (so 40% of the area would be variable cost in this case). Has anyone tried this?

Comment: You could just use a shape for this, instead of trying to do it in a cell.

Comment: @BigBen I agree with doing it in a shape, for appearance.  And that would also provide the ability to size the shape in accordance with the value.  The `ColorStops` property does afford the ability to size each color portion.  I just don't like the appearance for this purpose -- prefer sharp margins.

Comment: Thanks guys - I didn't about the data bars (gradients etc.) at all. Given the time constraints, I'll go with the data bars for now...but later on may try with shapes as well.

Answer (score 1):

I have a pretty dirty workaround for you, but it is doing the trick:

You use conditional formatting and custom number for making it work.

[image: Workaround for in-cell gradient fill]

First, in cell `D4`, type `=D5` to get the fixed value. Then, you **change the custom number format to “Demand”**.

[image: Custom number formating]

Now, you just need to **add conditional formatting with a gradient fill**, where the minimum value is 0 and the maximum value is the `=D5+D6`.

[image: Conditional formatting]

That works, but you must decide if it is practical for you.

Comment: Thanks Michael - this will work very well for me right now. Already experimenting with it. thanks!

Comment: This is a very interesting hack indeed :)

Comment: @BigBen Yes, but sometimes Excel forces us to use unconventional solutions :-).

Comment: ^^ Totally agree with that.